# NSPredicate exclude "name" in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I have this array of names (listedName) that I want to filter out  and remove in fbFriends array. How I can do it? Seems my clause is not working.

```
// add "names" to listed name array
NSMutableArray *aTempFriendList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int n = 0; n < [[self friendsList] count]; n++) {
    NSDictionary *dFriend = [[self friendsList] objectAtIndex:n];
    NSString *sName = [dFriend objectForKey:@"name"];
    [aTempFriendList addObject:sName];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name not in %@)", aTempFriendList];
[fbFriends filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `@"not (name in %@)"`.

Comment: yeah, just figured out... @"NOT (name IN %@)"